# Fitting Text to a Container when I zoom in

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive website, everything Is ok except that text inside that cloud that says "heyyy!..." as you see In the image below It's ok when I'm not zooming I like that behaviour

[image]

but when I zoom In I'm ending up with this ugly behaviour

[image]

I don't know how can I solve this problem I tried to put the entire unit of the robot image and the speaking cloud and the text inside a `div` and applying the position `relative` to that `div` and the position `absolute` to all the items inside it but it didn't work, any solutions please and thank you in advance

this is my code:

```css
  .header-box {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #33cccc;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
    position: relative;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .main-nav__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffcc;
  }

  .text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffcc;
    height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }

  .name {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: block;
    animation-name: moveInLeft;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }

.vector-1{
  position:  relative;
  height: 37vh;

}
  .img-dialogue {
    width: 60%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        bottom: 57%;
        z-index: -1;
  }

  .dialogue {
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #33cccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: 55px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .img-header {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header-box">
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="text">
  <h1 class="big-heading"><span class="name">M.Amine Elwere</span> Front-end <br /> Web developer</h1>
</div>
<div class="vector-1">
  <img src="../vector/Png for the web/header minou.png" data-aos="fade-up" class="img-header" alt="">
  <img src="../vector/Png for the web/png-dialogue-2.png"    data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="4000" class="img-dialogue" alt="">
  <h1 class="dialogue"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="5000">HEYY!...</h1>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I guess you would be better with percentages, when you zoom in, the div should go down a proportional size to keep it above the cloud... you could try to use top-margin property with percentage and try to find that sweet-spot where it will always be upon the cloud... maybe `top-margin: 76.4%`my example is just to illustrate you can use decimals...

Comment: Why exactly would you zoom?

Comment: You could prevent zooming on mobile in the first place: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: @IvanS95 that's for the best user experience I'm I right or  not?

Comment: Well, what I mean is that usually the content should look good without needing to zoom at all, so that zooming is irrelevant in the first place; so I'm not sure if you should be addressing that scenario instead of just making sure it looks good enough that zooming is not considered

Comment: @IvanS95 it looks Ok without zooming so should I leave it like this? sorry dude I'm just a beginner  doing my best to develop my skills

Comment: I don't mean bad; it's my opinion after all; I usually just focus on making sure everything looks good without any zoom, since doing that gives no reason for the user to zoom in lol; but if you want to address that potential case that's no problem at all, go ahead

Comment: right I think I'm gonna adopt your philosophy :p , because I'm stuck and I didn't get any helpful answer hhh

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is derived from the lack of a set font-size. When the browser renders your font, it will render it to the size, roughly of the browser. I'd recomend, if the text is positioned by you and not an image, then to use the value vw or vh. These are great for responsive designs and are initiated by the browser size similarly to percents. Then try to use the vw or vh to adjust the size of your font and position, and you should be good to go!
Here is an article by CSS-Tricks on Viewport Units - https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/